# Starting with OpenGL ES. Drawing using pixels

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, vertex

I'm starting to learn open GL in android (GL10) using java and I followed some tutorials to draw squares, triangles, etc.

Now I'm starting to draw some ideas I have but I'm really confused with the drawing vertexs of the screen. When I draw something using openGL ES, I have to specify the part of the screen I want to draw and the same for the texture...

So I started to make some tests and I printed a fullscreen texture with this vertexs:

```
(-1, -1, //top left
 -1, 1, //bottom left
 1, -1, //top right
 1, 1); //bottom right
```

Why is this fullscreen? Isn't the center of OpenGL coordinates at top left (0, 0)? Why with that vertexs the draw is correct? It seems that the center is really the real center of the screen and the width and height is from -1...1, but I dont really understand it because I thought that the center was at the top left...

Another question... I read a lot of c++ code where they print using pixels. It seems really necesary in videogames using pixels because needs the exact position of the things, and with -1...1 I cant be really precise. How can I use pixels instead of -1...1?

Really thanks and sorry about my poor english. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is this fullscreen? Isn't the center of OpenGL coordinates at top left (0, 0)? Why with that vertexs the draw is correct? It seems that the center is really the real center of the screen and the width and height is from -1...1, but I dont really understand it because I thought that the center was at the top left...

There are 3 things coming together. The so called *viewport*, the so called *normalized device coordinates* (NDC), and the projection from model space to eye space to clip space to NDC space.

The viewport selects the portion of your window into which the NDC range

```
[-1…1]×[-1…1]
```

is mapped to. The function signature is `glViewport(x, y, width, height)`. OpenGL assumes a coordinate system with rising NDC x-coordinates as going to the right and rising NDC y-coordinates going up.

So if you call `glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height)`, which is also the default after a OpenGL context is bound the first time to a window, the NDC coordinate (-1, -1) will be in the lower left and the NDC coordinate (1,1) in the upper right corners of the window.

OpenGL starts with all transformations being set to identity, which means, that the vertex coordinates you pass through are getting right through to NDC space and are interpreted like this. However most of the time in OpenGL you're applying to successive transformations:

- modelview

and

- projection

The modelview transformation is used to move around the world in front of the stationary eye/camera (which is always located at (0,0,0)). Placing a camera just means, adding an additional transformation of the whole world (view transformation), that's the exact opposite of how you'd place the camera in the world. *Fixed function OpenGL calls this the* **MODELVIEW matrix**, *being accessed if matrix mode has been set to* GL_MODELVIEW.

The projection transformation is kind of the lens of OpenGL. You use it to set if it's a wide or small angle (in case of perspective) or the edges of a cuboid (ortho projection) or even something different. *Fixed function OpenGL calls this the* **PROJECTION matrix**, *being accessed if matrix mode has been set to* GL_PROJECTION.

After the projection primitives are clipped, and then the so called *homogenous divide* applied, which is creating the actual perspective effect, if a perspective projection has been applied.

At this point vertices have been transformed into NDC space, which then gets mapped to the viewport as explained in the beginning.

---

Regarding your problem: What you want is a *projection* that maps vertex coordinates 1:1 to viewport pixels. Easy enough:

```
glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
if( origin_lower_left ) {
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
} else {
    glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
}
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Now vertex coordinates map to viewport pixels.

---

#### Update: Drawing a full viewport textured quad by triangles:

OpenGL-2.1 and OpenGL ES-1

```
void fullscreenquad(int width, int height, GLuint texture)
{
    GLfloat vtcs[] = {
      0, 0,
      1, 0,
      1, 1,
      0, 1
    };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vtcs);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vtcs);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: really thanks. I tried your piece of code but it doesn't show anything. I put: glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1); and then tried to draw with this vertexs: float screenVertex[] = {
    0, 0,
    0, KTE.GAME_HEIGHT,
    KTE.GAME_WIDTH, 0,
    KTE.GAME_WIDTH, KTE.GAME_HEIGHT
  }; but doesn't show anything. It has to draw like: bottom-left, top-left, bottom-right, top-right isnt it?

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm trying to draw a texture into a square (two triangles: i dont have GL_QUAD in opengl ES)

Comment: Now I'm having problems to draw a square using two triangles with the new glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1)... i cant show anything

Comment: @user949336: If using a triangle strip. The order should be bottom-left, bottom-right, top-left, top-right. For a triangle fan it's bottom-left, bottom-right, top-right, top-left. I usually use 2 GL_TRIANGLES or a GL_TRIANGLE_FAN as a replacement. Note, that if you always a full screen textured "quad", don't bother with those GAME_WIDTH, GAME_HEIGHT constants. Just use glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, ...) and -1, 1 as vertex coordinates.

Comment: Really thanks man... that worked perfectly. I didnt know about GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, i was using GL_TRIANGLES.

Comment: I have a last little questions: Using your code, the texture doesn't appear, but if I use your array only for the screen coordinates and for the textures use this order: top-left, bottom-left, top-right,
bottom-right, then works perfect. What could it be? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

By default opengl camera is placed at origin pointing towards negative z axis.
Whatever is projected on the camera near plane is the what is seen on your screen.
Thus the center of the screen corresponds to (0,0)

Depending on what you want to draw you have the option of using GL_POINT, GL_LINE and GL_TRIANGLE for drawing.

You can use GL_POINTS to color some pixels on the screen but in case you need to draw objects/mesh such as teapot, cube etc than you should go for triangles.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm trying to draw a square with a texture in a concret position, but I only know the android coordinates, not the openGL ones.

Comment: You can read about Opengl projection matrix, and use two triangles for drawing your textured square

Answer (score 2):

You need to read a bit more to get things clearer. In openGL, you specify a viewport. This viewport is your view of the OpenGL space, so if you set it so that the center of the screen is in the middle of your screen and the view to extend from -1 to 1, then this is your full view of the OpenGL prespective. Do not mix that with the screen coordinates in Android (these coordinates have the origin at the top left corner as you mentioned). You need to translate between these coordinates (for touchevents for e.g.) to match the other coordinate system.

Comment: I'm using: gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height); where width and height is the size of the screen... What is going on there? Reading it says that the first two values are the lower left corner, so... the center is at the bottom left? This is confusing me more... And what I have to do to transform the -1..1 to pixels? Really thanks.